# Limit of Convergent Sequence Property Proof Help

Tags: real-analysis, limits, convergence-divergence

I have a question about this property:

Let $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} a_n = a$, then $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}(ca_n) = ca$ for all $c \in \mathbb R$

If we consider when $c$ doesnt equal $0$, my book's proof says:

Consider $|ca_n - ca| < \varepsilon$, then we have $|c||a_n-a|<\varepsilon$.

Since we know that that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} a_n = a$, we can make $|a_n-a|$ small as we want, and in particular, choose $M$ such that $$|a_n-a| < \frac{\varepsilon}{|c|}$$ for $n \geq M$.

Then we have $|ca_n-ca| < \varepsilon$.

So my question is: since we know that the original limit exists, then by definition, for every epsilon there exists a $M$, such that whenever $n\geq M$, then $|a_n - a| < \varepsilon$. When the book says we can make $|a_n-a|$ small as we want and we "choose" $M$, then is it because $\varepsilon$ is arbitrary so we can have an $\varepsilon$ in form of $\displaystyle \frac{\varepsilon}{|c|}$, or is it because we know since the original limit exists, that there will an exist an $M$ such that $$|a_n - a| < \frac{\varepsilon}{|c|}$$ where $\frac{\varepsilon}{|c|}$ is a particular $\varepsilon$ (out of the arbitrary $\varepsilon$ to choose from) ?

Sorry for the long winded question, I'll try to clarify if my questions aren't clear

Comment: I think both are acceptable. I preferred the latter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first reason is the right one.

Let $\epsilon'=\frac{\epsilon}{|c|}$, then by the existence of the original limit, there exists $M$ such that $\forall n>M,|a_n-a|<\epsilon'=\frac{\epsilon}{|c|}$

Answer (score 2):

$a_{n}$ converges to $a$ so given $t>0$ there exists $N$ such that $n \geq N \Rightarrow |a_{n}-a|<t$. Let $\epsilon >0$ and $t=\frac{\epsilon}{c}$. $(c>0)$